# how to capture dynamically updated web element value(document.title) in python?

Tags: python

I am using bottle to host a simple html page which changes the page title on load. 
The HTML page code:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize(){
                var z=1234;
                document.title = z;}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize();">
        hi
    </body>
</html>
```

My bottle hosting code:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/:anything')
def something(anything=''):
   return template('C:/test1.html')

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

I am trying to capture the updated document.title using python.
so far I have tried urllib,mechanize,htmlparse but all of them were returning "title" instead of 1234.

a sample mechanize code that I have tried is:

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open("http://localhost:8080/hello")
print br.title()
```

Please help me.

Comment: The title is updated using JavaScript, which most Python HTTP-client implementations will not evaluate. If the JavaScript on the website is really that simple, you could try extracting the `z=1234` part instead.

Comment: :) thanks for your response, but you got me there. I have diluted the logic in order to make my question simple but the value of z is not that easily available. actually the value z is assigned like this..

var z = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(shape.getPath().getArray());

So do you see any way for me to extract that value out?

Comment: Looks like there are in fact ways to execute JavaScript on websites using Python: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/8049747/1114687

Comment: looks promising ... checking them out..thanks again. :)

Comment: Ok, good luck! I've flagged the question as a duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python), so anyone finding the question via the search function will find the answer linked above more easily.